# Downloading a file from Big query to GCS is having extra double quote around string data

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, google-cloud-storage

I am working on data extration from big query to gcs .
When I am downloading data ,my string data ishaving extra double quotes around it like below:

```
"""Account""=""2024"",""name""=""xyz"""
```

Data in big query view looks good. I am using conacte and collasce in my view query to create a view and from there. I am extracting data using BigQueryToGCSOperator use in airflow.

I want data in below format after extraction:

```
"Account""="2024","name""=""xyz"
```

I would want to return the values with only with single use of double quotes around the values

Comment: Maybe try using a simple PythonOperator which transforms the output into the desired format?